# How do I set the margin for the glossary item in my Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, glossaries

I have a table of contents and I use the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package to make my glossaries. At some point in my code, I have the command `\printglossary[type=glossarytype]` which prints my glossary. The problem is the glossary word in my table of contents is not aligned with my chapters (which are numbered). I need my glossary entry in ToC to have a little space at the left, where would normally go a chapter number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the package option `numberline` (in addition to `toc`).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[toc,numberline]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you must have it like that, I guess you could remove `[toc]` from the package declaration; create a new chapter called 'Glossary' and `\printglossary[type=glossarytype]` there. There may be a "better" way, but that'd do it for ya.